# PCB showing same readings pattern with and without component

Tags: arduino, pcb, pcb-design, adc, pcb-fabrication

I am doing an Arduino-like project on an old but "apparently" intact PCB. Part of the circuit involves a potentiometer, connected to an ADC, giving readings from -1.0 to +1.0.

There's a pattern of readings of fixed values above and below the potentionmeter's ideal reading. For instance if the potentiometer's reading must be 0.6, then the reading I will get will be alternating between those three values 0.6, 0.6 - 0.02, and 0.6 + 0.02.

I then removed the potentiometer to see the reading without it, which would ideally be 0.0 exactly, just to find it alternating between the values, 0.0, 0.02, and -0.02.

Note that in a brand new PCB from the exact manufacturer, with and without the potentiometer, the readings won't be of alternative values at all, so it indeed is an aging-induced change in the PCB, and not a mere industrial-out-of-the-box imperfection. What are the most likely reasons for this result?

Comment: please provide a schematic diagram for the board

Comment: Please provide schematics and component values.

Comment: @Justme
I don't have experience in pbc design at all. But the bottomline, I am asking about the commercially abundant two controllers of PS4, and Xbox. They use and alps module for the joy stick, the pots of white is what I removed, which are 10K ohm. That all what I know about it frankly.

This is a diagram of the xbox pcb, I hope it helps.
https://fccid.io/RDDCYG80899192D/Schematics/SCHEMATICS-584711.pdf

Comment: @jsotola
I don't have experience in pbc design at all. But the bottomline, I am asking about the commercially abundant two controllers of PS4, and Xbox. They use and alps module for the joy stick, the pots of white is what I removed, which are 10K ohm. That all what I know about it frankly.

This is a diagram of the xbox pcb, I hope it helps.
https://fccid.io/RDDCYG80899192D/Schematics/SCHEMATICS-584711.pdf

Comment: without the pot connected the input is floating

Comment: @Juraj I've mentioned that the readings pattern appear with and without the potentiometer being connected.

Comment: So how did you connect your Arduino to the pot? We don't know what you are doing and how, imagine that you are instructing someone to replicate the experiment identically to verify results.

Comment: @Justme It is not an arduino, it is a ps4 controller. I am testing old and new and in between ds4 controllers. Trying to know which part causes which noise pattern in the input readings. To repeat the experiment, you need differently aged ds4 controllers in terms of hours of moving the potentiometers (consuming its life cycles) from 0 to 100hours. Then measure readings with the pot, without it, and with a brand new pot instead. What happened is that I get a consistent specific noise distinct from all other noises that is present even if only the adc and rest of pcb is there without the pot.

Comment: @Juraj digging a bit into it, the microcontroller might be a FM8P51. This uses a resistance to frequency conversion method to digitise the inputs, so it won't be floating.